# Where do I store custom values/content?

Tags: 8

I'm creating a page "from scratch", with routing, controller, etc. The content of my page is created by code, buy I want to add a editable component (the description of the page).

I don't want to use blocks, because I don't wanto to give too many permissions to editor role.

I could create a "custom content" content type to store content and then add node content from code.

Other ways? I was thinking to use configurations, but if I export all configurations with "drush cex", this config will be overridden after editing. A good way could, if it's possibile, to exclude this single component from export.

Other ideas?

Comment: I always check this site of the drupal documentation when I am unsure which type of information I need:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2120523

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about what is the question here. In general:

If you want to store content, create a ContentEntityType that extends ContentEntityBase. If you want to create a configuration, create a ConfigEntityType that extends ConfigEntityBase.

What you need sounds like a ContentType where you create your main content by code and have another Form to add/modify the content of a "page description" field in the ContentType. Maybe you can also use "Node" that could save a lot work.

Comment: Yes, a custom content entity could be the solution, thanks. I've to check how to add a "machine name" to these entities.